# Question about Kallenberg's proof of Doob-Dynkin Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

The following is the proof for the Doob Dynkin Lemma from Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability. In the theorem, $(S,\mathscr{S})$ is assumed to be Borel, i.e. Borel isomorphic to a Borel subset of $[0,1]$. Thus, it is natural to assume that $S \in \mathscr{B}([0,1])$. But how can we modify $h$, to further reduce to the case when $S = [0,1]$?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, there exists a measurable function $\phi:S\to [0,1]$ s.t. $\phi^{-1}$ is Borel. So if you find measurable $h':T\to[0,1]$ s.t.
$$
\phi \circ f=h'\circ g,
$$
then $f=h\circ g$, where $h=\phi^{-1}\circ h'$ is the required mapping.

Comment: Why does there exist a measurable $\phi : S \to [0,1]$ s.t. $\phi^{-1}$ is Borel?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Borel spaces (also called *standard Borel spaces* by some authors):

1. countable ones, for which the $\sigma$-algebra is necessarily discrete, and
2. uncountable ones.

If $S$ is countable, then the conclusion of Lemma 1.13 can be proved directly.
If $S$ is uncountable, then by a standard result (*) about Borel spaces, for every uncountable Polish space (i.e., a separable and completely metrizable topological space) $X$, there is a Borel isomorphism $\phi : (S, \mathcal{S}) \to (X, \mathcal{B}(X))$.
In particular, $X = [0, 1]$ is one such uncountable Polish space.
Thus, without loss of generality one may assume $S = [0, 1]$ since they are Borel isomorphic anyway.

(*) See e.g. Theorem 7.1 in [these notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275d.1.18f/PDFs/Standard-Borel-Spaces.pdf).